Churches with Abelard or Socinus view on atonement?
What are the names of some nowadays Churches or Denominations that hold Peter Abelard or Faustus Socinus views on atonement or Salvation?
I mean Churches that hold the Moral or Example theory of atonement.

How much is actually known about Socinus' view of the atonement? Wikipedia only says that he reject propitiatory atonement, but doesn't indicate what he thought instead. And I'd be surprised if there was any church that didn't teach Abelard's moral example theory - the debate is not over that, but whether in addition Jesus was also a substitute (and if so, how), whether the Father truly has wrath, and so on. Most churches teach multiple theories of the atonement, differing primarily on emphasis.
